# Is there a way to auto save data in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to auto save data entered in a temp area (risk is a calculated value based on the values entered) on google sheet. I have a working space and all my logs is now needing to be saved for later review.
see sample sheet.
[Created a sample data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hu2u.png)

Thanks

Comment: Google always autosaves your data. If this is not what you meant - please reformulate your question. Maybe you mean that you want to dubpllicate the data into a backup sheet?

Comment: You are right, I want it duplicated/auto-saved elsewhere. I don't use the area designated as "temp" to store data. So I want the values entered in the section duplicated elsewhere.

Comment: There are several ways to do so. You can use e.g. IMPORTRANGE to create a duplicate into a secondary spreadsheet (it will update though when changes in the original spreadsheet are made. Otherwise you can write a script that will copy paste the values of your spreadsheet either automatically on each edit or manually on button click when you desire.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do it. You'll need to create a log of sorts and have the dashboard reference the bottom most entry. If you have App Script experience, that would be the better solution, however without it you could use the a Google Form for editing the dashboard. There wouldn't be any formulas alone that will work for this due to needing to hardcode the inputs, and formulas can only return values as arrays (mirror/change values in other cells).

You can use a Google Form that is linked to the spreadsheet so that someone has to submit the form with the inputs to change the dashboard. You would then use a =Max() function on the timestamp column, and then either Vlookup or Index(match()) to return the variables for the dashboard based off Max(timestamp).

The alternative method would be to create basically set of cells similar to the input table, and add a button that if clicked, takes, the values and updates them in the variables for the dashboard, but also logs them on another sheet. ([It would be something like this](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3529693?hl=en))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. I end up using the below script to accomplish the task.

```
function FormExec() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sinput = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var soutput = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var input = sinput.getRange(14, 3, 15).getValues();

  var flatin = [].concat.apply([], input);
  soutput.getRange(soutput.getLastRow()+1, 1,1, 15).setValues([flatin]);
  soutput.insertRowAfter(soutput.getLastRow());
  Logger.log(input);  
}
```